# Select parent and child attribute value

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath

I have an xml file like below:

```
<tag>
   <file name="name1">
      <error message="error1"/>
      <error message="error2"/>
   </file>
   <file name="name2">
      <error message="error1"/>
      <error message="error2"/>
   </file>
</tag>
```

I hope to get a next result:

```
name1: error1, error1;
name2: error1, error1
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
*//file/@name | //file/error/@message*
```

But this, of course, does not work. Can I implement a map?

Comment: are you sure about the expected results, because it seems like output is different than HTML snip,`error1` and `error2` are there. please make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath 3.1,

```
string-join(/tag/file ! (@name || ': ' || string-join(error/@message, ', ')), '#')
```

where # represents a newline character escaped according to the conventions of your host language, e.g. `\n` for Java, `&#xa;` for XSLT.

For XPath 2.0 replace `A!B` by `for $a in A return B` and replace `A||B` by `concat(A, B)`

XPath 1.0: not possible without host language support.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with XPath-2.0 or above. You can use the following expression to create a string as a result. It uses the appropriate delimiters `,` and LF`&#xa;`.

```
for $nam in /tag/file/@name, $msg in $nam/../error return concat(if (generate-id($msg) = generate-id($nam/../error[1])) then concat($nam,': ',$msg/@message) else $msg/@message, if (generate-id($msg) = generate-id($nam/../error[last()])) then ';&#xa;' else ',')
```

The output is:

```
name1: error1, error2;
name2: error1, error2;
```

This output differs a little bit from your desired output above (`error2` instead of `error1`) and a trailing `;`. If you need to get rid of the last `;`, you can do so by implementing the same principle like with the line-feeds.

P.S.: The approach for checking for the first and last elements seems to be sub-optimal, so there's probably room for improvement.

Comment: Yep, I've attempted the improvement in my answer.